# htaccess Replace part of all URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, replace

How to replace all URLs with "/?h=down" in last address with "#do" and redirect to new address.

example:
http://my.site.com/any/?h=down

redirected to:
http://my.site.com/any#do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the query string using `RewriteCond` and then make a redirect using the `R` flag paired with the `NE` flag.

> NE|noescape
>
> By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be
>   converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents
>   that from happening.

Doing something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^h=down$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/#do [R,NE,L]
```

Since you also like to remove the original query string you could try and add a trailing `?` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/#do? [R,NE,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. i use this code but my url address
http://my.site.com/any/?h=down
redirected to
http://my.site.com/any/#do?h=down
i want to remove ?h=down form address.

Comment: @user1571462 - I updated my answer with a solution which I think will work with a redirect.